# Rails console command to get a record when the foreign key pattern does not match the default pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could you please show how to write the rails command when the association is created with different foreign key(author_id) deviating from default naming (user_id)?

In this example:

```
class User
  has_many games
end

class Game
  belongs_to :player_white, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "player_white_id"
  belongs_to :player_black, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "player_black_id"
end
```

Rails console if I type the command:

```
>> User.games.
```

I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column games.user_id does not exist
```

I understand that it is not able to find the foreign key user_id as the foreign key will be either player_white_id or player_black_id. But to specify that in rails console command?

I tried
`User(:user_id => :player_white_id)`. But it does not work.

Game table in schema file:

```
create_table "games", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "player_white_id"
  t.integer  "player_black_id"
  t.string   "name_for_game"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Games has foreign keys `"player_white_id" and "player_black_id"` but actually belong to the same class User.

I am trying to get the games played by the player in rails console:

```
>>user1 =User.create(:username => "White", :password => "123")
>>user2 = User.create(:username => "black", :password => "123")
>> Game.create(:player_white_id => user1.id, :player_black_id => user2.id)
```

Now if I try to access

```
>>user1.games
```

It throws the above mentioned error.

Basically I want to get the list of games for a particular user. I know I can get by using the following query:

```
Game.where("player_white_id = ? or player_black_id = ?", user.id, user.id)
```

But I want to know if I can get using the User model. For example:

```
`User.game`
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your belongs_to looks good. Could you show us the Game migration?. You foreign keys have to be stored on the Game table and have the same name as the one you specify in your model. I'm not sure I understand your query. User.where(:id => id) needs you to have an actual value. Not a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Define `has_many :games` with foreign_key option.

```
class User
  has_many :white_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'player_white_id'
  has_many :black_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'player_black_id'

  # If you want all game
  def games
    Game.where('player_white_id = ? OR player_black_id = ?', self.id, self.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`User.games` will throw an error because there is not a method on the `User` class named `games`. There *is* a method called `games` on *an instance* of the `User` class though. Try creating a `User` with `Game`s first then try `User.first.games`.